# How to create a non single-shot timer in C?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I need to use a non single shot Timer (such as QTimer from the Qt library) in a C code for embedded Linux (by no single shot Timer I mean one that triggers once ever x seconds indefinitely till a "stop timer" is called, not one that triggers only once or one that blocks the code while it's counting).

Some libraries that are available to me do implement such a timer using signal handlers, but I would like to avoid using such a system ([I learned that is not the best solutio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065326/linux-timers-on-global-vars)n). I know I can emulate what I want with single shot Timers by restarting the timer (calling it again) once it's finished, and that is an acceptable solution (actually the libraries I talked about work that way), but I don't know how to implement that without blocking the running code till the timer is triggered.

And one more thing: I need to be capable of implementing more then just one of them (here is where signal handlers stop being a viable solution AFAIK).

So how could I do such a solution? The closes to what Qt's QTimer has to offer, the better!

Answer (score 3):

If you do need an unspecified number of triggers at varying intervals/times, a dedicated timer thread (as described by [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo) in another answer) has the least number of pitfalls in my experience.

Timers are a limited resource (the number of timers available is configurable, and varies from system to system, so you cannot make any sweeping statements like *"I'm sure there's enough for my purposes"*).

Signals interrupt blocking syscalls unless `SA_RESTART` flag is used; even then there are a few exceptions (see [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), *Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers* chapter for details).

---

A dedicated timer thread is built around two components:

1. A queue, list, tree, or heap holding all timer events

   A typical implementation only needs to know when the *next* event occurs, so a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) or a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) works quite well. I've found a min-heap to be simple and robust to implement, and efficient enough (*O(log N)* time complexity for both inserts and deletes); using absolute times (using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` in Linux) for the events as keys.

   Note that if you use the timer events as timeouts, you'll also need to make sure cancelling an event is efficient. In normal operation, timeouts are rare, so something like a web server is likely to cancel just about all the timeouts it sets, without any of them actually ever triggering.
2. A thread that waits for either the next event, or another thread inserting a new timer event

   Personally, I use an array to hold the min-heap of events, protected by a `pthread_mutex_t`, with a `pthread_cond_t` for other threads to signal on after adding a new event. Then, it's a simple matter to use [`pthread_cond_timedwait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_timedwait) to wait/sleep for either the specified time, or until a thread notifies of a new event, whichever happens sooner.

   When the next event occurs -- note that due to scheduling, you might find more than one separate event to occur, so you might not wish to sleep at all (but you might still check if new events were added) --, you perform the event. If the event is periodic, you reinsert it into the heap/queue, too, primed for the next time.

Choosing *how* events are performed is very important, and really, the only truly tricky bit. You can use flags -- switching from zero to nonzero is safe in practice, even if the change is not atomic, as long as you don't rely on any specific nonzero value --; you can cause a condition variable to be signaled or broadcast on; you can post a semaphore; you can raise a specific signal in a specific thread (even an empty signal handler will cause blocking I/O calls to interrupt, if the handler is installed without `SA_RESTART` flag; I've used this as an I/O timeout quite successfully); you can even use [`__atomic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) or [`__sync`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) to modify a value atomically if using GCC (or Intel CC, Pathscale, or Portland Group C compilers); and so on.

If you need a specific function to be called, I recommend using a separate thread (or, if most of the work in the application/program/game is done in these timer events, a thread pool) to execute the events. This keeps the timer thread simple and precise, while keeping all resource use easily controlled. The worker thread or thread pool should simply have a FIFO queue of events protected by a mutex and a condition variable, so that the timer thread can add each event to the queue and then signal on the condition variable to notify the (next) worker thread that work is available.

Indeed, in the couple of instances I used other event action models, I now believe the function worker model would have been easier. Especially if you make the worker functions to take a pointer (to a structure), defined by the caller, so that they all have the same signature, this interface becomes quite straightforward to implement, but extremely powerful and versatile.

There is one downside to the timer-thread plus worker-thread(s) approach, and that is the (minimal) added latency. The worker thread will not get the work *at* the appointed time, but a short while afterwards. However, if you have the worker thread get the current time, compare to the (un-adjusted) target time, and use that as a statistic to trigger the events correspondingly prior to the target time, you can typically take care of this issue. (I have not verified, but I do believe both Qt and GTK+ toolkits do continuously estimate this latency in a similar if not same manner.)

Questions?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options, none of which require any libraries beyond the standard C and POSIX libraries.

- POSIX timers API, e.g. [`timer_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and friends. These have flexible notification scheme based on `sigev`, which allows you to specify how you want to be notified (signal to a specific thread, creation of a new thread, or arbitrary signal). By specifying that the signal goes to a specific thread, you can set that thread up to be ready for async signals, and use `sig_atomic_t` to signal work to be done by the thread. The most interesting notification option is to use the creation of a brand new thread, but note that this can get expensive if the timer fires frequently.
- Linux `timerfd` API, e.g. [`timerfd_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html). These create timers that you can poll with `poll` or `epoll`, enabling you to add the timers to a low-level event loop, as well as operate on them in a perfectly thread-safe and signal-safe way.
- `alarm`. This uses the SIGALRM asynchronous signal, so again you'll want to use `sig_atomic_t` and a signal-processing thread to handle the timer.
- `select`, `poll`, or `nanosleep` on a dedicated timer thread: This is what QTimer usually does under the covers. You simply create a dedicated timer thread and have the thread repeatedly sleep. To keep the timer on schedule, you adjust the sleep time based on the length of each processing cycle.

The last option is the most portable, but also basically the most work (since you're implementing the timer yourself). The upshot is that you get to customize the "timer" completely since you're implementing it on top of a sleep primitive.